# C-ISAM file consistency

Tags: informix, b-tree

INFORMIX-SE 4.10.DD6:  I seem to be having spurious problems like missing pointers with C-ISAM files in my SE database. When I do 'bcheck -y FILE_123' it says it has rebuilt indexes and fixed the problem, but when I re-run bcheck on it again, it repeats the same error messages and says it fixed it, but not true! I know this is an unsupported/outdated version of SE, but if you can think of any other alternative to fixing this other than unloading/dropping table/re-create and load back in, I would appreciate any help. When I used SE 2.10.06, bcheck worked fine, but since moving up to 4.10, C-ISAM files and bcheck have been problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the old trick of:

- Create a new table with the same index structure as the table that is giving trouble.
- Copy the (almost empty) index file for the new table over the index file of the old one.
- Rerun bcheck.

Of course, you take precautions:

- You create the new table.
- You copy the data file of the troublesome index file somewhere.
- You copy the new index file beside it.
- Run bcheck on the new copies.
- Rerun bcheck on the rebuilt file.
- Only copy stuff over the database copy if everything looks OK.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks!..but I'm still wundering why bcheck is unable to repair it. Would it be a good idea to periodically unload the tables? I'm not using any transaction logging or audit table. would creating audits on just critical tables and recovering from audit work?

Comment: @Frank: There's no sensible answer - I have no idea why not, and neither will anyone else at this stage.  The software you are using is old enough to drink legally; who knows what vices and virtues it has picked up in its career so far.

Comment: understood!.. I'm almost done with a basic conversion of my app to Access 2010, but there's some things about A10 I really don't like, but my users want the integration with Excel and other Office modules.